# 2sxc change template between data types

Tags: types, 2sxc

Situation:
I have 1 app called **Text** which contains multiple Data types.
So we have data types like:
- Title and text
- Title, text and button
- Title, text and image

When I have first added the App module and choose a template from the "Title and text" data type, I can not change it to a "Title, text and image" template.

How can we fix this? It is quite annoying that we can't change the templates to anything after initial selection.

Answer (score 0):

Switching **views** once content has been added is restricted to **views** which are configured for the same content-type.

But if your **template** could handle both content types, just configure another **view** with the *same* template and the other content type and you'll be able to switch without having to create more **templates**